# Route-Me Embedding - MapView classes missing

Tags: iphone, git, mapping, cloudmade

I've been trying to get Offline Maps to work for a while now, but am pretty stuck now.  I've followed the instructions on the [Route-Me Embedding Guide](https://github.com/route-me/route-me/wiki/Embedding-Guide) to the letter but:

have no MapView.app - just libMapView.a and a missing RM Unit Tests.App - but looking at other posts, I'm not sure if this is a problem.

xCode cannot find RMMapView.h (and I suspect the RM other classes)

I've tried everything I can think of and searched for ages - any help warmly welcomed.  I'm kind of hoping once I've got past this that Offline Maps will be a cinch :)

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out now.  The Header Search path needed a / on the end.  Simple when you know.

Thanks.

Comment: Can u help me on integrate the library.i hope i done all the things as  per Route-Me Embedding Guide